# Presenter в adapter moxy

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Хотелось бы увидеть пример,как грамотно подключить presenter к адаптеру .
Если есть примеры - поделитесь пожалуйста)

Comment: А к какому адаптеру и как подключить? Вы, наверное, про RecyclerView? Если да, то непонятно что именно вы хотите в ответе увидеть. По идее надо просто из Presenter во View в адаптер данные передать и его об этом уведомить. Ну и дальше всё от деталей зависит - надо ли клики обрабатывать etc

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
да
Просто бы хотелось увидеть пример не классический  где фрагмент или активность наследуется от интерфейса и происходит магия  по взаимодействию view и презентера. А именно нестандартный про Recycler VIew.
Просто у нас что получается. Есть фрагмент у фрагмента презентер
в фрагменте ресайкл вью и у ресайкла вью свой адаптер?

Answer (score 1):

Если разговор идет о Presenter и RecyclerView.Adapter то никак. Presenter не должен ничего знать о адаптере. Презентер знает о View (ее интерфейсе).

Например вам надо получить данные из сети и показать пользователю:

- View в нужном вам состоянии ЖЦ говорит: "Презентер, дай ка мне данные"
- Presenter идет в сеть (или еще куда-то, не важно), получает данные и он знает что во View есть метод `updateView(List<Data> dataList)`. И все, на этом его знания о View заканчиваются.
- А вот как обновить View решает сама View. Это может быть как обновить список, так и показать любой другой UI. Завтра RecyclerView умрет или вы захотите переписать ваш UI и изменения в Presenter-е должны быть минимальны.

Comment: я и имел ввиду реализация mvp на примере интерфейса view адаптера